# Sharepoint 2010 - SPMonitoredScope ... performance implication?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Does SPMonitoreScope have any performance implication? I mean, can I leave the SPMonitored scope in production environment? or is it better practice to remove this from code?

Many Thanks,

Joseph,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what MSDN says - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512758.aspx

Performance Considerations

Using SPMonitoredScope to wrap code has a very low performance hit. However, it should be noted that if a section of code wrapped by SPMonitoredScope were to contain a loop that performed a high number of iterations (for example, iterating through XML nodes that are returned by a SharePoint Foundation 2010 Web service), the call stack included on the Developer Dashboard could increase in size exponentially, making it difficult to decipher the information displayed.
Best Practices

A tip for the best and most effective use of SPMonitoredScope:

```
All calls to external components, such as custom databases, external Web services, and so on, should be wrapped with SPMonitoredScope. This will make it easier for administrators to identify them as points of failure, and to isolate the problem quickly.
```

Regards,
Nitin Rastogi

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly a performance hit using monitored scopes. That being said, it's relatively small for the tyoe of work it does. Best practice is to switch it off on production environments unless you are investigating a specific issue.